# OAuth2: How to request current authentication status?

Tags: angular, authentication, oauth-2.0

In my Angular app I use OAuth2 (github) for authentication. The problem is that the user session is killed every time I refresh the page.

In the case of Firebase Authentication I can get the current authentication status every time the page is reloaded using the following code:

```
 this.user = this.angularFireAuth.authState.pipe(
            switchMap(user => {
                if (user) {
                    //bla
                } 
                else {
                    return of(null);
                }
            })
  );
```

This way the user session does not get killed by reloading the page. But how can I do the same thing in the case of OAuth2 authentication?

Answer (score 0):

I found a work-around ... I simply save the authentication status in the session storage ... the session storage can then be queried every time the page is loaded:

```
sessionStorage.setItem('isAuthenticated', 'true');
sessionStorage.getItem('isAuthenticated');
```

Comment: And now the user can set "isAuthenticated" to true himself via devtools, i don't think this is what you want.

Comment: Thank you for your comment ... how could the user do that ... as far as I can see he/she can't access the code?

Comment: But the user has access to the sessionStorage

Comment: I see ... ok but how can I solve this problem in another way without this security hole?

Comment: For JWT authentication it's basically: User authenticates himself => get a access token from backend => store it in localstorage => refresh it in certain timeframes  => when the user reloads authenticate the user with the token. I don't know but i think for OAuth2 it's pretty similar ?